# mongoDB $nin does not work how it should

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, social-networking

I'm trying to design a social network and I have a `User` Schema which has an array of strings that is `user.friends_list`. When I run the code, the result is not what I expect. It gives me back some of the members that are on the `friends_list`.

The `user.friends_list` is fine and when I run the query in mongo shell I see that the friend list is exactly what it should be.

```
module.exports.getMembersWithouFriends = function(user, callback) {
    User.find({ username: { $nin: user.friends_list } }, callback)
}
```

**Mongo Shell**

```
> db.users.find({'username':'mm'}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59cc1abbf8362823385cb2a9"),
        "first_name" : "mm",
        "last_name" : "mm",
        "email" : "mm@mm.com",
        "username" : "mm",
        "password" : 
        "posts" : [ ],
        "friends_list" : [
                "roy",
                "david",
                "rr",
                "dd",
                "shahar",
                "mm"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

When I console log the result I'm getting from mongo, I'm getting "roy" and "david" back.

Comment: Do you mean `db.users.find({ username: { $nin: ["roy", "david"]} }` is not working ? and it returns documents with "roy" and "david" ?

Comment: no .. i mean that `User.find({ username: { $nin: user.friends_list } }, callback)` returns a document that contains both "roy" and "david" but if i use **Mongo Shell** it does work as it should

Comment: try to use `user.friends_list.map(x => String(x)) `

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT i have tried it but i get the same results. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well seems like this code was working just fine and the problem was in my database. i had some not existing users that were still in the users DB.